# Evaluating function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate this function, which is gradient of integral with variable limit of integration:
$$
u(x,y,t)=\nabla(\int_{v(x,y)}^\infty \frac{e^{-b(t-\tau-c)^2}}{\sqrt{\tau^2-{v(x,y)}^2}} d\tau  )
$$
where $v(x,y)={\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\over a}$, and $a,b,c$ are arbitrary constants. This was my attempt:

```
ClearAll;
a=1.;
b=2.;
c=3.;

g[x_,y_,t_]:=Integrate[Exp[-(b (t-τ-c)^2)]/Sqrt[τ^2-(Sqrt[x^2+y^2]/a)^2],
    {τ,Sqrt[x^2+y^2]/a,Infinity},Assumptions->{t>0}];

f[x_,y_,t_]:=Grad[g[x,y,t],{x,y}];

(*try to evaluate function at point [20,30,1]*)

f[x,y,t]/.{x->20,y->30,t->1}
```

but is not working. I am not expecting, that I will get function $u(x,y,t)$ in explicit form as a function of time $(t)$ and spatial coordinates $(x,y)$,but the values of function at some dicrete time points for given $x,y$ would be great.
Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution can be obtained for the specific case `t -> c`.

```
Grad[Integrate[(Exp[-(b (t - τ - c)^2)]/Sqrt[τ^2 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/a)^2]) /. t -> c,
    {τ, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/a, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False], {x, y}] // FullSimplify
(* {-((b E^(-((b (x^2 + y^2))/(2 a^2))) x Sqrt[a^2/(x^2 + y^2)] Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)/a^2] 
   (BesselK[0, (b (x^2 + y^2))/(2 a^2)] + BesselK[1, (b (x^2 + y^2))/(2 a^2)]))/(2 a^2)), 
   -((b E^(-((b (x^2 + y^2))/(2 a^2))) y Sqrt[a^2/(x^2 + y^2)] Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)/a^2] 
   (BesselK[0, (b (x^2 + y^2))/(2 a^2)] + BesselK[1, (b (x^2 + y^2))/(2 a^2)]))/(2 a^2))} *)
```

`Integrate` returns unevaluated for other values of `t`, unfortunately.